# Making sense of biolatency stats for sequential and random reads

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, ebpf

I ran ebpf biolatency tool in two scenarios. In both cases, the page cache was cleared using

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

A. Using fio tool for sequential reads

```
ngd@stannis:/mnt/catalina$  sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/biolatency
[sudo] password for ngd:
Tracing block device I/O... Hit Ctrl-C to end.
^C
     usecs               : count     distribution
         0 -> 1          : 0        |                                        |
         2 -> 3          : 0        |                                        |
         4 -> 7          : 0        |                                        |
         8 -> 15         : 0        |                                        |
        16 -> 31         : 12       |****************************************|
        32 -> 63         : 0        |                                        |
        64 -> 127        : 0        |                                        |
       128 -> 255        : 0        |                                        |
       256 -> 511        : 1        |***                                     |
       512 -> 1023       : 0        |                                        |
      1024 -> 2047       : 1        |***                                     |
      2048 -> 4095       : 0        |                                        |
      4096 -> 8191       : 0        |                                        |
      8192 -> 16383      : 1        |***                                     |
     16384 -> 32767      : 1        |***                                     |
     32768 -> 65535      : 1        |***                                     |
     65536 -> 131071     : 0        |                                        |
    131072 -> 262143     : 0        |                                        |
    262144 -> 524287     : 0        |                                        |
    524288 -> 1048575    : 2        |******                                  |
```

B. Using fio tool for random reads

```
Tracing block device I/O... Hit Ctrl-C to end.
^C
     usecs               : count     distribution
         0 -> 1          : 0        |                                        |
         2 -> 3          : 0        |                                        |
         4 -> 7          : 0        |                                        |
         8 -> 15         : 0        |                                        |
        16 -> 31         : 105      |                                        |
        32 -> 63         : 2768     |                                        |
        64 -> 127        : 91255    |**********                              |
       128 -> 255        : 360700   |****************************************|
       256 -> 511        : 15758    |*                                       |
       512 -> 1023       : 17       |                                        |
      1024 -> 2047       : 0        |                                        |
      2048 -> 4095       : 12       |                                        |
      4096 -> 8191       : 1        |                                        |
      8192 -> 16383      : 1        |                                        |
     16384 -> 32767      : 2        |                                        |
     32768 -> 65535      : 0        |                                        |
     65536 -> 131071     : 0        |                                        |
    131072 -> 262143     : 2        |                                        |
    262144 -> 524287     : 0        |                                        |
    524288 -> 1048575    : 23       |                                        |
```

I am trying to make sense of this data.

1. Why does the sequential read stats have more standard deviation than in random read stats?
2. Can I assume that the accesses that are in the 16-31 usec range (for Seq reads) pertain to the actual data and the higher latency accesses are related to the filesystem/ block device metadata?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

To proceed further, you would need to identify which processes are making these accesses. You can do that with [biosnoop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/biosnoop_example.txt):

```
# ./biosnoop
TIME(s)     COMM           PID    DISK    T SECTOR     BYTES   LAT(ms)
0.000004    supervise      1950   xvda1   W 13092560   4096       0.74
0.000178    supervise      1950   xvda1   W 13092432   4096       0.61
0.001469    supervise      1956   xvda1   W 13092440   4096       1.24
0.001588    supervise      1956   xvda1   W 13115128   4096       1.09
```